# android-studio 's program crashes while trying to run it

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

hey everybody i'm french so please excuse my bad english .
 i'm a programmer who's learning kotlin and i'm making my first program with android studio so i want to make a button(add) who when pressed will add the content of two textboxes(imp1/imp2) and write it as a result in a third textbox(result) like a calculator but when i press the button it crashes and close the app

```
    add.setOnClickListener{
    result.text = (imp1.text as Int + imp2.text as Int) as CharSequence
                    }
```

Comment: Use `(imp1.text.toInt() + imp2.text.toInt()).toString()`

Comment: thanks for your reply but it says **unresolved reference** for the 'toInt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `imp1` and `imp2` are `EditTexts`, 
so `imp1.text` and `imp2.text` are of type `Editable` and not `String`. 
If `result` is a `TextView` you must do this:

```
result.text = (imp1.text.toString().toInt() + imp2.text.toString().toInt()).toString()
```

or if `result` is an `EditText`:

```
result.setText((imp1.text.toString().toInt() + imp2.text.toString().toInt()).toString())
```

Comment: thank's @forpas it works <3 <3 <3  it's the first time that i ask something in a forum and i never thought it was so helpful

Comment: yeah sure sorry i'm kinda newbie on this platform

Answer (score 0):

You can still use old java method

(Integer.parseInt(imp1.text.toString()) + Integer.parseInt(imp2.text.toString()))

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: `Process: com.example.dalid.myapplication, PID: 11447
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x9
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:410)
        at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:465)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5589)
        at com.example.dalid.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:16)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)`

Comment: ` at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)` **it may help**